# Why $J_k(0)^T$ ~ $J_k(0)$?

Tags: jordan-normal-form

Why these two Jordan blocks are similar: $J_k(0)^T $ and $J_k(0)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Because if $k_1+k_2+\dots + k_s=k$, all $k_i\geqslant 1$, $s>1$ then
$$
\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{s}J_{k_i}(0)\right)^{k-1}=O
$$
whereas
$$
J_k(0)^{k-1}\not=O.
$$